# Объявление двумерного массива

Tags: c, массивы

Я задал константе значение

```
 #define N 100
    int main()  {
    int A[N] [N]; //почему это неправильно? И как нужно чтобы компилятор не ругался (VS2017) ? 
    int i, j;
   .....
```

Comment: Не вижу, чтобы VC++ ругался на ваше объявление. Может, он у вас на что-то другое ругается? Вы не стесняйтесь приводить всю информацию, а то поступаете как почтальон Печкин: "У меня для вас посылка, но я вам ее не дам!"

Comment: как именно ругается компилятор?

Comment: Зачем вы удалили остальной код?

Comment: Он вам нужен был?

Comment: И на что вам теперь отвечали? Получается, глядя на вопрос - два придурка откуда-то нашли проблему, которой в заданном вопросе нет, так что ответы никакого отношения к вопросу не имеют... Верните все назад, иначе получается глупо.

Comment: Что за бессмыслица? Вопрос звучит как " почему 2+2 равно 5"? В приведенном коде все правильно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваше

```
int N;
```

из-за

```
#define N 100
```

превращается в

```
int 100;
```

что для компилятора совершенно непонятно - потому что не является корректной конструкцией С. Просто уберите эту строку - она вам не нужна.

Answer (score 0):

В коде есть `#define N 100` и `int N;`. Одну из N необходимо переименовать. И никода больше не давать переменным имена констант/макросов (и вообще не использовать однобуквенные имена).

Comment: scanf("%d", &N);
int A[N][N]={0};      почему так нельзя делать?

Comment: Это независимый вопрос. Новый вопрос - новая тема.